# $(X,T)$ a topological space. Let $A\subseteq X$. Suppose $\forall a\in A\exists U\subseteq X, a\in U\subseteq A$. Show $A\subseteq X$ is open

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question:

$(X,T)$ a topological space. Let $A\subseteq X$. Suppose $\forall a\in A, \exists$ open $U\subseteq X$, such that $a\in U\subseteq A$. Show $A\subseteq X$ is open

and I just learned what a topological space is. A Topological space $T$ of a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $\emptyset, X$ are in $T$, and all the elements in $T$ are closed under intersection and finite union. The exercise above asks us  to prove that $A$ is open, that is, $A$ is in the topological space $T$. We have the information that $U$ is in the topological space $T$, because the exercise says that $U$ is open in $X$. I could go and try to prove that $A$ is closed under intersection and finite union, and try to prove that $\emptyset\in A$ and $X\in A$, but I don't have the rule that defines which elements of $X$ are in the topological space, therefore I'll need to do it in another way. I remember my teacher taking the union of all $a$ and proving it's equal to $A$. How that helps and why?

Comment: Union of arbitrary of open set is open, that's why.

Comment: You might want to know that in the current use of mathematical English, $T$ is called *topology*. The *topological space* is technically the pair $(X,T)$ but, when no other topology on $X$ has been specified, $X$ alone is commonly referred to as the topological space.

Comment: Moreover, you seem to be confused as to what has which property. $T$ is closed under *finite intersection*, which means that, whenever we have $A,B\in T$, then $A\cap B\in T$. A specific set $A\in T$ is *not* "closed under intersection* (whatever it means). Similarly, $T$ is closed under *arbitrary union*, which means that if you have a family $\mathfrak F\subseteq T$, the subset of $X$$$\bigcup\mathfrak F:=\{x\in X,\:\,\exists A\in\mathfrak F,\ x\in A\}$$ is in $T$. No single set in $T$ is "closed under union" (whatever it means). No open set contains $\emptyset$. $T$ does. Etcetera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several confusions here, let's go through them.

> and I just learned what a topological space is. A Topological space $T$ of a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $\emptyset, X$ are in $T$, and all the elements in $T$ are closed under intersection and finite union.

A topological space is a set together with a topology $T$, this is a collection of subsets of $X$, called open sets. This collection of sets is closed under finite intersection and union. (Note that 'finite' is for the intersections not the unions.)

That is, for example, if you have open sets $U \in T$ and $V \in T$, then $U\cap V \in T$. And so on.

> The exercise above asks us  to prove that $A$ is open, that is, $A$ is in the topological space $T$. We have the information that $U$ is in the topological space $T$, because the exercise says that $U$ is open in $X$.
>
> I could go and try to prove that $A$ is closed under intersection and finite union, and try to prove that $\emptyset\in A$ and $X\in A$, but I don't have the rule that defines which elements of $X$ are in the topological space, therefore I'll need to do it in another way.

No, you need to show that $A$ is an element of $T$. The properties apply to a collection of subsets of $X$ not one subset of $X$.

> I remember my teacher taking the union of all $a$ and proving it's equal to $A$. How that helps and why?

You know that for each $a \in A$ there is some $V_a \in T$ such that $a \in V_a \subset A$. Then $\bigcup_{a\in A} V_a \subset A$ and also $A = \bigcup_{a\in A} \{a \} \subset \bigcup_{a\in A} V_a$. Thus this union is equal to $A$. Since each $V_a \in T$ their union is also in $T$ as $T$ is closed under unions. Thus $A$ in $T$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\in A$, denote by $U_a$ an open subset containing $a$ such that $U_a\subset A$, $A=\bigcup_{a\in A} U_a$ is open since a union of open subsets is open.

Comment: why $A=\bigcup_{a\in A} U_a$?

Comment: $U_a\subset A$ this implies that $\bigcup_{a\in A}\subset A$, on the other hand, $a\in A$ implies $a\in U_a, a\in \bigcup_{a\in A}U_a$ this implies that $A\subset \bigcup_{a\in A}U_a$.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, your teacher's suggestion looks good.

We want to prove that $A$ is open.

What do we know about $A$ ?

We know if we pick $a\in A$ there is an open set $U_a$ such that $a\in U_a$ and $U_a\subseteq A$.

We use this to show $A$ is open.

To do this consider the set $\bigcup\limits_{a\in A}U_a$, this set is open because it is a union of open sets.

We now show this set is in fact equal to $A$.

We do this by showing $\bigcup_{a\in A}U_a\subseteq A$ and $\bigcup_{a\in A}U_a\supseteq A$..

First we show $\bigcup_{a\in A}U_a\subseteq A$, this is easy, because $U_a\subseteq A$ for all $a\in A$.

Now we show $\bigcup_{a\in A}U_a\supseteq A$. To do this select an arbitrary $a'\in A$, we must show it belongs to $\bigcup_{a\in A}U_a$, to so this it suffices to show that it belongs to at least one of the sets in the union, in this case we have $a'\in U_{a'}$.

Comment: Fine, except that your notation $U_a$ seems to suggest that you are using the axiom of choice. More simply, just show that $A$ is the union of the collection of *all* open subsets of $A.$

Comment: that's actually a good suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without the Axiom of Choice: For each $p\in A$ let $S(p)=\{t\in T: p\in t\subset A\}$ and let  $U(p)=\cup S(p).$

The hypotheses imply that $\{p\} \subset  U(p)\subset A$ for every $p\in A.$

That implies $A=\cup_{p\in A}U(p)$ because$$ A=\cup_{p\in A}\{p\}\subset \cup_{p\in A}U(p)\subset \cup_{p\in A}A=A. $$ Since $U(p)\in T$ for every $p\in A $, we have $A=\cup_{p\in A}U(p)\in T.$

Answer (score 0):

The topology $T$ is not used anywhere in your question after "Suppose".  So, I suspect, there is a typo in the question.

More importantly, it seems you could use getting some clarity about the concept of a topological space.  The $T$ is not "the topological space".  The pair $(X, T)$ is.  The $T$ is just a certain collection of subsets of $X$.

I think, what would help you is first taking a familiar topological space.  For example, first rephrase and do your problem with $X$ being the Euclidean plane: $X = {\bf R}^2$, and $T$ being the collection of all sets in that plane that are open (in the sense of the Euclidean distance).  (You will notice that these open sets have the properties of a general topology:  arbitrary unions and finite intersections of open sets are open, and $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open.  That was the inspiration for defining a general topological space.)